# Replacing special chars in a string with a single unique char

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like so:

```
string inputStr = "Name*&^%LastName*#@";
```

The following Regex will replace all the special chars with a '-'

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _]");
someStr = rgx.Replace(someStr, "-");
```

That produces an output something like:
    Name---LastName---

How do I replace '---' with a single '-' so the output looks like this:

```
Name-LastName
```

So the question is how do I replace all the special chars with a single '-'?

Regards.

Comment: `How do I replace '---' with a single '-'` If you do this the result will be `Name-LastName-`.

Comment: Why not just split via the regex and concat it back after?

Comment: I would put the `-`, which is now between two spaces, at the end of the character class. The character class would be `[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]`. This is the rule when `-` means '-' and not an interval...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 \- _]+");//note - character is escaped
```

or

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+");//or use - as last character
```

But this will give `Name-LastName-` Is this okay or..?

If you don't need `-` at last position you can use the following code as well. Credit goes to 
@MatthewStrawbridge. You can see in comments.

```
string someStr = rgx.Replace(inputStr, "-").TrimEnd('-');
```

will output `Name-LastName`.

**Edit:** As @pguardiario pointed in comments updated my answer to escape `-` since range(`[]`) has special meaning for `-` character. If we need `-` as a literal we need to escape it or make it first or last character of the character class in order to behave as literal.

Comment: If it's not okay, you can always combine it with `Trim`.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Great idea, I thought to modify regex for that

Comment: Thanks Sriram, and Matthew that did the job.

Comment: @pguardiario What am missing here? I just modified OP's code with minimal change? will this fail anywhere?

Comment: `-` has special meaning within `[]` of a regex. I realize the original was flawed but it's your job to fix it.

Comment: It's better. It wasn't clear if ` - ` was supposed to be a range. `a-zA-Z0-9_` is the same as `\w` so in general you're probable looking for `[^\w -]+`, but who really knows.